# Remove overlapping objects while ensuring the most area covered

Tags: object-detection

Below is an example. There are non-unique boxes highlighted with red and blue. I aim to remove these boxes, but one thing is that not all from the same overlapping group can be removed. It is like keeping the most of the union of overlaps. Forgive me, if the formulation of the problem is not clear. I'll try to explain with an example.

Removing a completely overlapping boxes (red) is simple.

1. Subtract the intersection area between all paired boxes from the original area of each box
2. Remove the box if the subtracted area <= 0 (completely overlapped).

The problem gets harder if I set a threshold that boxes with unique areas less than the threshold gets removed. For the case of the three boxes at the top right, all three are subject to removal, but the middle one should be removed to keep the most areas covered. If either of the other two is removed, they are still eligible for removal.

This problem arose from getting the bounding box of ROI from an image for object detection. There were boxes that overlapped too much and was considered duplicate or redundant for training. I couldn't quite formulate the problem so couldn't reach far with searching online for answers. I'd appreciate any insights or directions.

[image]